# Failed to write HTTP message: no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting error 500 on this one. I have already added in my java but still can't get any data from the java `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}`

This is the error

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.capstone.codegum.Codegum.Objects.BusinessRole["usersId"]->com.capstone.codegum.Codegum.Objects.User_$$_jvst2fa_8["handler"])
```

BusinessRole.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="Business_Roles")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}
public class BusinessRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long businessRoleId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="role")
    private Roles roles;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="business_id")
    private Business business;

    public User getUsersId() {
        return usersId;
    }

    public void setUsersId(User usersId) {
        this.usersId = usersId;
    }

    public Long getBusinessRoleId() {
        return businessRoleId;
    }

    public void setBusinessRoleId(Long businessRoleId) {
        this.businessRoleId = businessRoleId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="users_id")
    private User usersId;

    public Roles getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Roles roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Business getBusiness() {
        return business;
    }

    public void setBusiness(Business business) {
        this.business = business;
    }



}
```

if you need more infos please tell me I will edit the post immediately

Comment: did you try @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) ?

Comment: it works but I still can't get my data from the jpa